# Update nested object property based on the value of another property - JS

Tags: javascript, object, lodash

I have a nested object and I would like to traverse it and update the property of 'error' to true if the 'value' property is an empty/falsy value. If the value of 'value' property is empty string, empty array, empty object, undefined or null, the corresponding 'error' property should be changed to true.

This is what I have:

```js
const data = {
  "item1": {
    "value": 88,
    "error": false
  },
  "item2": {
    "value": 655,
    "error": false
  },
  "item3": false,
  "item4": [],
  "item5": "",
  "item6": "",
  "item7": false,
  "item8": {
    "value": undefined,
    "error": false
  },
  "item9": {
    "value": [],
    "error": false
  },
  "item10": {
    "value": [],
    "error": false
  },
  "item11": {
    "value": [],
    "error": false
  },
  "item12": false,
  "item13": {
    "subItem1": {
      "name": "Country",
      "group": {
        "value": {},
        "error": false
      },
      "instances": []
    },
    "subItem2": {
      "name": "Group",
      "group": {
        "value": {},
        "error": false
      },
      "instances": []
    },
    "subItem3": {
      "name": "Product",
      "group": {
        "value": {},
        "error": false
      },
      "instances": []
    }
  }
}

function iter(o) {
  Object.keys(o).forEach(function(k) {
    if (o[k] !== null && typeof o[k] === 'object') {
      iter(o[k]);
      return;
    }
    if (o['value'] === undefined || !o['value'] || _.isEmpty(o.value)) {
      o['error'] = true
    }
  });
}


iter(data)

console.log(data)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.20/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

expected output:

```
{
  "item1": {
    "value": 88,
    "error": false
  },
  "item2": {
    "value": 655,
    "error": false
  },
  "item3": false,
  "item4": [],
  "item5": "",
  "item6": "",
  "item7": false,
  "item8": {
    "value": undefined,
    "error": true
  },
  "item9": {
    "value": [],
    "error": true
  },
  "item10": {
    "value": [],
    "error": true
  },
  "item11": {
    "value": [],
    "error": true
  },
  "item12": false,
  "item13": {
    "subItem1": {
      "name": "Country",
      "group": {
        "value": {},
        "error": true
      },
      "instances": []
    },
    "subItem2": {
      "name": "Group",
      "group": {
        "value": {},
        "error": true
      },
      "instances": []
    },
    "subItem3": {
      "name": "Product",
      "group": {
        "value": {},
        "error": true
      },
      "instances": []
    }
  }
}
```

Please advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

! check for undefined, 0, '', and null

for [] and {} use JSON.stringify() === '[]' to check if it empty

```js
const data = {
  "item1": {
    "value": 88,
    "error": false
  },
  "item2": {
    "value": 655,
    "error": false
  },
  "item3": false,
  "item4": [],
  "item5": "",
  "item6": "",
  "item7": false,
  "item8": {
    "value": undefined,
    "error": false
  },
  "item9": {
    "value": [],
    "error": false
  },
  "item10": {
    "value": [],
    "error": false
  },
  "item11": {
    "value": [],
    "error": false
  },
  "item12": false,
  "item13": {
    "subItem1": {
      "name": "Country",
      "group": {
        "value": {},
        "error": false
      },
      "instances": []
    },
    "subItem2": {
      "name": "Group",
      "group": {
        "value": {},
        "error": false
      },
      "instances": []
    },
    "subItem3": {
      "name": "Product",
      "group": {
        "value": {},
        "error": false
      },
      "instances": []
    }
  }
}

function iter(o) {
  Object.keys(o).forEach(function(k) {
    if (o[k] !== null && typeof o[k] === 'object') {
      iter(o[k]);
      return;
    }
    if (!o['value'] || JSON.stringify(o['value']) === '{}' || JSON.stringify(o['value']) === '[]') {
      if (!o.hasOwnProperty('value')){
        return;
      }
      o['error'] = true
      return;
    }
   
  });
}


iter(data)

console.log(data)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.20/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Why does subItem1 have a new field 'error'?

Comment: Wait le me check it. I checked, it's because subitem "value" is undefined, 
let me update the code

Comment: Done editing, I added property checking, so if there's no "value" property we didn't add the error true value

Answer (score 0):

Here is an iterative solution using [object-scan](https://github.com/blackflux/object-scan). It might be a bit easier to reason about

```js
// const objectScan = require('object-scan');

const myData = { item1: { value: 88, error: false }, item2: { value: 655, error: false }, item3: false, item4: [], item5: '', item6: '', item7: false, item8: { value: undefined, error: false }, item9: { value: [], error: false }, item10: { value: [], error: false }, item11: { value: [], error: false }, item12: false, item13: { subItem1: { name: 'Country', group: { value: {}, error: false }, instances: [] }, subItem2: { name: 'Group', group: { value: {}, error: false }, instances: [] }, subItem3: { name: 'Product', group: { value: {}, error: false }, instances: [] } } };

const modify = (data) => objectScan(['**.value'], {
  rtn: 'count',
  filterFn: ({ parent, value }) => {
    if (!value || (value instanceof Object && Object.keys(value).length === 0)) {
      parent.error = true;
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
})(data);

console.log(modify(myData)); // how many "error" values found
// => 7

console.log(myData);
// => { item1: { value: 88, error: false }, item2: { value: 655, error: false }, item3: false, item4: [], item5: '', item6: '', item7: false, item8: { value: undefined, error: true }, item9: { value: [], error: true }, item10: { value: [], error: true }, item11: { value: [], error: true }, item12: false, item13: { subItem1: { name: 'Country', group: { value: {}, error: true }, instances: [] }, subItem2: { name: 'Group', group: { value: {}, error: true }, instances: [] }, subItem3: { name: 'Product', group: { value: {}, error: true }, instances: [] } } }
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/object-scan@14.0.0"></script>
```

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of [object-scan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-scan)